# Analytic mysql function to retrieve rows of each category depending on another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with numerous columns including category and rating. In the entire table, there are two category values: category 1 and category 2. Rating values range from 1 to 5. The following anayltic query retrieves 4 products of each rating irrespective of category, so, 4 products with rating 1, four products with rating 2 and so on... The (id > 10) is of no particular significance)

```
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT x.* 
    FROM 
      (SELECT   t.*, 
                  CASE WHEN @rating != t.rating THEN @rownum := 1 
                     ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 END 
                AS rank, 
                  @rating := t.rating
                AS var_rating 
       FROM products t 
       JOIN (
             SELECT @rownum := NULL, @rating := ''
                   ) r 
              WHERE ( id > 10 ) 
              ORDER BY t.rating, price
            ) x
     WHERE 
        x.rank <= 4
```

I wish to modify it to retrieve 4 products of each rating of each category. Please can someone help.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) is fantastic at the "select-n-per-group" problem.

I'm basically following it in my solution.

These queries selects the 4 cheapest products per (category,rating). In the case of a tie in price it picks the one with the smaller id.
If you just wanted 4 products per (category,rating) regardless of price then skip out the `p.price<=products.price` line.

Method 1 (easy to understand):

```
SELECT *
FROM products
where (
   select count(*) from products as p
   where p.category = products.category 
     and p.rating = products.rating
     and p.price <= products.price
     and p.id < products.id             -- in case of tie with price
) < 4
ORDER BY category,rating,price;
```

The inner query says to count up how many items are cheaper than or the same price as you, and the outer query says to pick only things that have less than 4 items cheaper than/same price as you.

If you want to use user variables you can try:

```
SET @num := 0, @cat := '', @rating := '';
SELECT category,rating,id,price
FROM (
   SELECT category,rating,id,price,
      @num := if(@cat = category AND @rating=rating, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @cat := category as dummy,
      @rating := rating as dummy2
  FROM products
  ORDER BY category,rating,price,id
) AS p WHERE p.row_number <= 4;
```

Where the inner query orders your table by category, rating, price and id, and assigns row numbers within each (category,rating) pair. The outer query selects the first 4 from each.

---

The last method on that page would have this query, **but** it doesn't work unless you have some sort of index on your columns (and my MySQL foo is not enough to work it out):

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD KEY(???);

SET @num := 0, @cat := '', @rating := '';
SELECT category,rating,id,price,
      @num := if(@cat = category AND @rating=rating, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @cat := category as dummy,
      @rating := rating as dummy2
FROM products FORCE INDEX (???)
GROUP BY category,rating, ???
HAVING row_number <= 2;
```

which supposedly relies on MYSQL doing an `ORDER BY` in the `GROUP BY` and hence making sure rows are ordered as requested.